# How do I make OpenLayers.Class.create() work in Openlayers 2.12?

Tags: openlayers-2

At version 2.12 some functionality has been changed and moved to the "deprecated.js"
I have the following code which I want to be able to run without "deprecated.js". how can I convert it ?

```
OpenLayers.Layer.MapInfoRESTHandler = OpenLayers.Class.create();
OpenLayers.Layer.MapInfoRESTHandler.prototype = 
    OpenLayers.Class.inherit( OpenLayers.Layer.Grid, {...
```

I know OpenLayers.Class() is funtion now , but I'm not sure how to use it in current syntax so it will create the same class as the code above (and same with inherit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to create a new class which inherits from one class, you can use this structure:

```
OpenLayers.Layer.WMS = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Layer.Grid, {
    CLASS_NAME: "OpenLayers.Layer.WMS
    });
```

writing a class for openlayers you should check out OpenLayers Coding Standards [here](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/CodingStandards). it has an example too. beside this you can check out peterrobins Class structure [here](http://www.peterrobins.co.uk/it/olstructure.html).

if you want to altering a class method, you can use this structure:

```
OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults.prototype.defaultKeyPress = function...
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Thank you Aragon , Question is , In my code example , what do I replace "OpenLayers.Class.create();" with ? because OpenLayers.Class(...) need to get argument , but in the example code I wrote , there isn't any argument.

Comment: if you want to use prototype you can change only one or two methods of your class, but if you want to create new class which is inherited from one class, you have to use first code that i have shared with you. i dont think you need create() method.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are trying to create a class that inherits from a parent one. I would do it using the function [*OpenLayers.Util.extend()*](http://goo.gl/YofYJ).

If you want to see examples of the usage of *OpenLayers.Util.extend()*, you can see the source code of OpenLayers controls, which inherit from *OpenLayers.Control*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the example I'm going to provide here is exactly what you asked for, I know it's a late answer but this might help others.

I had the same problem with the pgRouting module in OpenLayers 2.12, in which the starting routing-application code doesn't work with OL 2.12:

```js
var SinglePoint = OpenLayers.Class.create();
SinglePoint.prototype = OpenLayers.Class.inherit(OpenLayers.Handler.Point, {
createFeature: function(evt) { this.control.layer.removeFeatures(this.control.layer.features);
OpenLayers.Handler.Point.prototype.createFeature.apply(this, arguments);
}
});
```

The changes it needs in order to replace the deprecated component and add functionality with OL 2.12 is as follows:

```js
var SinglePoint = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Handler.Point);
SinglePoint.prototype = OpenLayers.inherit(SinglePoint, {
createFeature: function(evt) { this.control.layer.removeFeatures(this.control.layer.features);
OpenLayers.Handler.Point.prototype.createFeature.apply(this, arguments);
}
});
```

It's true that the `OpenLayers.Class.create();` is deprecated from OL 2.12 but this is a way to make it work. For more info about deprecated components in OpenLayers 2.12, have a look here: [Deprecated components in OL 2.12](http://svemir.co/2012/10/09/deprecated-components-in-openlayers-2-12/)